# Excel to SQL server : UPDATE table with equivalent of : SUMIF divide by SUMIF

Tags: sql-server, excel

I'm moving an Excel database into an SQL Server database and I have some problems translating this excel query into SQL.

In my Excel, I have two tables (table1 and table2).

In the table1, there is a column 'total_operation' who divides the result of two 'SUMIF' :

```
= SUMIF(table2[operation_value]; table2[operation_id]; [@[operation_id]]) 
 / SUMIF(table2[quantity]; table2[operation_id]; [@[operation_id]])
```

table 1 (@)

| invoice_number | operation_id | **total_operation** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A11 |  |
| 2 | A12 |  |
| 3 | A13 |  |

table2

| operation_id | operation_value | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A11 | 111.45 | 2 |
| A11 | 34.00 | 1 |
| A11 | 29.00 | 3 |
| A12 | 20.40 | 1262 |
| A12 | 34.00 | 5 |
| A12 | 1257.00 | 18 |
| A13 | 1.45 | 435 |

The result of the first row for '**total_operation**' would be : [(111.45 + 34.00 + 29.00)] / [2 + 1 + 3)] = 174,45 / 6 = **29,07**

Do you think it's possible to make an UPDATE of the table1.total_operation_value in one single query?

Comment: Storing an aggregate value in a table is generally a poor idea; as soon as the value(s) it's aggregating change (due to an `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE`) then the aggregated values are either wrong or you need to recalculate them all. You are often far better off using a `VIEW` if you want to expose aggregate values.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! There is no movement in the table2, she is almost fixed. But there is every day new rows in the table1 with new invoice coming

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I quite understand your tables (if that's the whole table then you probably want an unique ID column somewhere, although I can't quite tell what's going on), so sorry if this answer is quite vague and confusing; but table 2 is consistent and operation A11 always has **exactly** the same values I think @larnu is right and a View might help. (Actually whatever's going on, I think larnu is probably right)

If you had a view such as

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS
SELECT operation_id,  sum(operation_value) /sum(quantity) as total_operation
FROM table2
```

and changed table1 to just have invoice number and operation id, then whenever you needed the quantity you could do

```
select  t1.invoice_number, t1.operation_id, v.total_operation
from table1 t1
join view_name v on v.operation_id = t1.invoice_number
```

That way your table doesn't go out of date if you ever decided to add a row to table2 in five years time, as it's already accounted for.
If you think you might have an invoice with more than one item on it, you probably want a one to many invoice to operation id table somewhere, but the view would still be useful.

Otherwise if it's always consistent and you don't need the rows in table two, you could just replace table two with a table of just one row per operation id and the total operations value, if you have them in Excel already you should be able to transfer them over as hard values.

Comment: For a better understanding, table1 is receiving the result of an OCR invoice extracting tool (throught a logic app/power automate système). I hide these columns in table 1.

In table2, i have a listing of discount special operation and i make a join on the operation_id to automaticaly reconciliate the two database and make an automatic check validation (goal of the whole system)